# None Type float error help -- deduction = miles_Driven * mile_Ddm TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, nonetype

I am new to python and I need help. I have already tried to solve this error but I can't find the solution, I am using None so that values can be held inside of them given by the user input.

```
tax = 0.30
mile_Ddm = 0.56
gov_tax = None
take_Home = None
deduction = None
mine = None

def total(money_Made, gov_tax, take_Home):
   gov_tax = money_Made * tax
   take_Home = money_Made - gov_tax 
   return take_Home

def deductable(mile_Ddm, deduction, gov_tax, miles_Driven):
    deduction = miles_Driven * mile_Ddm
    mine = deduction - gov_tax
    return mine

user_input = float(input("How much did you make today?  "))
print("This is your take home pay: ", total(user_input, gov_tax, take_Home))

user_input = float(input("How many miles did you drive today? "))
print("This is the amount of your deductable: ", deductable  (user_input, mile_Ddm, deduction, gov_tax))
```

Comment: You're assigning local variables in the functions, not the global variables.

Comment: If you want `total` and `deductible` to be able to modify globals, then you need to (1) remove those globals from the parameter lists and (2) declare them `global` in those functions.

Comment: Thank you, both comments helped me solve the issue.